# how to store my result in a recursive function

Tags: matlab, recursion

i have a *matlab  function* for listing all files in a folder, including its children folders. i can display them all , but i have no idea about how to store them in my **output** variable .

```
function out = searchfolder(varargin)
if nargin<1
    helpdlg('no input floder');
    return;
else
curfolder=varargin{1};
end
if ~isdir(curfolder) || length(dir(curfolder)) < 3
return;
end

children = dir(curfolder);
%eliminate '.' and '..' 
children = children(3:end);
allfiles = {};
for i=1:length(children)
   child = children(i);
   thisone = fullfile(curfolder,child.name);
    if child.isdir
       searchfolder(thisone);
    else
       disp(thisone);

    end
end
```

so how to figure out this problem?

Comment: You need to concatenate your output from the recursive `searchfolder` call. e.g. `out = [out searchfolder(thisone)]` (after initializing your output)

Comment: ok,thanks @excaza , i'll try

Answer (score 0):

with excaza's help ,  i have the code :

```
function out = searchfolder(varargin)
out = {};
if nargin<1
%        helpdlg('no input floder');
    return;
else
curfolder=varargin{1};
end
if ~isdir(curfolder) || length(dir(curfolder)) < 3
return;
end 
children = dir(curfolder);
%eliminate '.' and '..' 
children = children(3:end);
allfiles = {};
for i=1:length(children)
   child = children(i);
   thisone = fullfile(curfolder,child.name);
    if child.isdir
       out = [ out ;searchfolder(thisone)];
    else
       disp(thisone);
    out = [out;{thisone}];
    end
end
```